# I am looking for an equation that will on input of a natural number the output is equal to a number of 1s

Tags: linear-algebra

For example
1 would return 1,
2 would return 11,
3 would return 111,
-1 would return 0.1,

Comment: Note, natural numbers don't include negative integers. So "integer" would have been the correct word.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for $$\left |\frac{10^n-1}{9}\right |$$

$1\mapsto1$,$2\mapsto11$,...

$0\mapsto0$

$-1\mapsto0.1$,$-2\mapsto0.11$,...

The |'s are there to make it work for negative numbers as well.

Comment: Negative numbers.  Smart.  But shouldn't they be around just the n.  Not the entire fraction?

Comment: @fleablood No, because then -1 would map to 1 and -2 would map to 11. user276446 wanted -1 to map to 0.1!

Comment: Oh!  I guess I didn't read that for into the question.  I thought he *wanted* f(-2) = 11 because ... ah, crud.  I'm tired.

Answer (score 0):

$f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}10^i = 1 + 10 + 100 + ... + 10^{n-1} = \frac{10^n - 1}{10 -1} = \frac{10^n - 1}{9}$

==edit===

Well, phoey.  I didn't take in negative numbers as Alex did.  Put an absolute value around it.

$n > 0; f(n) = \frac{10^n - 1}{9} = |\frac{10^n - 1}{9}|$

$n = 0;  f(n) = 0 = |\frac{10^n - 1}{9}| $

$n < 0; f(n) = 111...1*10^{-|n|}=f(|n|)*10^n=\frac{10^n(10^{|n|} - 1)}{9} = \frac{1 - 10^n}{9}= |\frac{10^n - 1}{9}|$